# Use meld in Kate editor, Flatpak version, to compare files and find differences

Tags: editors, kate, meld

In Kate editor I have been using meld to compare files and find differences.

I was happily using the contextual menu that you get when you have two files open and you right-click on the tab of the non active document, as explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670486/129648).

However, after moving to the Flatpak version of Kate, this doesn't work anymore... I still have meld installed, and the "compare with active document" menu appears, when I right-click on the tab. However, I get a message: "The selected program can not be started. Maybe is not installed". I guess this has to do with the "sandboxing" of Flatpak. I have messed with some of the settings for Kate in "Flatseal" (the sandboxing manager for Flatpak), in particular granting to Kate access to all system resources, but I can't get meld back. Maybe I need to export an environment variable? but which one?

Answer (score 0):

Depends one which version of Kate you are using. Older versions of Kate with flatpak weren't able to access executables on the host. Latest version of the Kate should fix this.

Besides that, you can directly compare documents inside starting from version 22.12. Right click on a tab and click compare with active document. Under the hood it uses git to get the diff and then visualizes it in the gui. Yes, it means git must be installed and available in the PATH.

Comment: Thank you @Waquar! 
The version I used was the latest possible (which is the reason why I was using FlatPak ;) )
The procedure you mention (right-click on the tab) is exactly what I was doing, but I only get some sub-menus, mentioning meld (and a couple of other similar external tools).
I can't try your answer because I uninstalled the flatpak version of Kate, and switched back to the one from the Mint repository.

Comment: Unfortunately I think latest Kate is not available via flatpak. But Kwrite is available and has this feature, https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kwrite if you are on Linux mint based on Ubuntu 22.04 lts, then building Kate yourself is really easy :)